# ActiveRecord model subclass NoMethodError on 'create'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a Rails 4 beta app (on Ruby 2) and I'm getting an error I can't make sense out of.

I've got some specs that are failing because my model class has no method 'create', even though I'm inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base.  The error message is calling my class a module (`undefined method 'create' for Topic:Module`), and that seems odd.

**spec/models/topic_spec.rb:**

```
require "spec_helper"

describe Topic do
    it "should create a new topic given valid attributes" do
        Topic.create!({:created_by_id => 1, :title => "Test" })
    end
end
```

**app/models/topic.rb**

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
    include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection

    validates :title => :presence => ture
    validates :created_by_id => :presence => true
end
```

**Error message:**

```
$ rspec spec/models/topic_spec.rb

    F

    Failures:

      1) Topic should create a new topic given valid attributes
         Failure/Error: Topic.create!({:created_by_id => 1, :title => "Test" })
         NoMethodError:
           undefined method `create' for Topic:Module
         # ./spec/models/topic_spec.rrc:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a module or namespace also named Topic that is getting loaded first and so in your tests, Topic is not referring to your class.  Are there any other files that have Topic in them, even something like class Topic::Question or similar?  If so, try taking them out or being explicit about it.  For example, changing:

```
class Topic::Question < ActiveRecord::Base
```

to

```
class Topic
  class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
```

Comment: Right on the money.  The app is called 'Topic'.  Thanks a lot!